# stop google now mid-rant?

Tags: google-now

I use Google Now on an Android tablet, and I wanted to know if there is a way that I can stop it speaking in middle. Usually when I search for something it will read off the top result, and I often don't need it to read off the entire thing. Is there a way I can stop it after I've heard enough?

Comment: What version of android? Maybe tap outside of the Google now search screen?

Comment: I'll try it out, but if it works, put it in a question. I can't award a bounty to a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4qebru/ok_google_explore_over_150_google_now_voice/) post, where the OP has created this [web site](http://ok-google.io/) dedicated to known Google Now commands and their variations. There is no direct way of *silencing*, so here is a workaround

When Google is reading the results and you heard enough, say *OK Google mute the volume*

This silences Google by setting volume to zero. To revert to normal volume, say *OK Google set the volume to `x`* , x being a number from 1 to 15 (you will need to experiment to get to comfort level) or *OK Google set the volume to full*

Tested this on searches like *OK Google define aerodynamics*, where the rant (as you say ) was long enough . I haven't been able to configure to read out search results, say on Donald Trump :)

Comment: Thanks, sometimes if I search something solidly factual, like "What was Barcelona's last match?", it'll read out the result. I guess your answer is a bit of a workaround, but it does the trick.